# How to control vim message display time

Tags: vim

Is there a way to control display time of messages in vim?

For example, when searching in vim and hitting the bottom, it will display:

```
  search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP
```

Even if after several seconds, and the cursor already moved away, the message still won't go away.

The only way to disappear such messages I can come up with is to do

```
:redraw
```

However, I hope to find a way to do it manually for all such messages after a period of time, say 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Vim doesn't provide a useful way to set precise delays without interfering with user interaction.  The best you can probably hope for is this:

```
:autocmd CursorHold * :echo
```

I chose `:echo` because it's less visually disturbing than `:redraw` and it should clear the command area of messages.

Note that this will only work when you are in normal mode and *do not* press a key for a period of time (usually four seconds).  For why, see:

```
:help CursorHold
:help 'updatetime'
```

In other words, this isn't going going to be very effective.  There has been discussion about creating a true event loop in Vim that can be hooked into, but unless and until that happens what you want won't be available.

Comment: thanks for letting me know definitely that this feature is not available yet...

Answer (score 0):

If the `updatetime` value is small, `echo` will clear the cmd line msg too quickly. We can use the `timer_start()`[^1] function to *delay* the execution of echo. Here is what works well for me:

```
function! s:empty_message(timer)
  if mode() ==# 'n'
    echon ''
  endif
endfunction

augroup cmd_msg_cls
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorHold * call timer_start(25000, funcref('s:empty_message'))
augroup END
```

The value `25000` is measured in miliseconds, so it means roughly 25 seconds after cursorhold. You may tweak this value to what suits you.

[^1]: it seems that the `timer_start()` is only available for Vim 8.0+.